# How to make a third person character control walk based on where user is gazing through google cardboard in unity 3D

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am making a VR model of my university campus using unity3D.

I have created a model of my university and now my task is to make the third person character move in the direction where user will be gazing.

EX: if I look straight I should keep seeing which ever comes in the way .
If I look at left the 3rd person character should be able to turn left.

that means depending upon my head movement it should walk.

PL NOTE : I will be using Google cardboard VR Gear

How can I achieve it? I know I have to make a script in C# / javascript but I am not so familiar with it.

Please suggest !!!

Answer (score 1):

Add your character as child of camera so it can rotate according to head movement. Then add your movement script to camera object and write code to move in forward direction. you can use controller or trigger to move it.